# Defining Variables inside macro

Tags: macros, makefile

How do you define a variable inside of a GNU make macro? I am using GNU Make 4.0 and whenever I do an assignment the variable is empty:

```
define TEST_MACRO
    $(info $(1))
    test_var := $(1)
    $(info $(test_var))
endef

$(call TEST_MACRO,test)
```

Outputs:

```
test
(blank line)
```

I have tried using recursive expansion for the assignment but I get the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which version of Make you're using, and there are subtle differences between versions in the handling of macros. But this works for me (using GNUMake 3.81):

```
define TEST_MACRO
    $(info A $(1))
    test_var := $(1)
    $$(info B $$(test_var))
endef

$(eval $(call TEST_MACRO,test))
```

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 4.0, I've updated the question with that information.

Comment: I tried that and it works, could you explain a bit as to why I have to escape and evaluate anything that isn't directly using the arguments?

Comment: @Lerp: I hate to admit it, but I'm not actually sure why these things are necessary; they just work.

Comment: The reason it has to be this way is that the value will be expanded twice by make.  First, the `$(call ...)` function will expand `TEST_MACRO`.  Then, the `$(eval ...)` function will expand the result of the `$(call ...)` function.  You can learn a bit about this by replacing the `eval` function with `info`.  That will show you the result of the `call` function, that `eval` will evaluate.  Try it both ways and see the difference.  Without extra escaping, the `info` functions are expanded by `call`, _before_ the variable is set by `eval`.

Comment: @MadScientist: That makes such perfect sense that I *cannot* figure out how I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @MadScientist: Wow :-) The trick with the "info" really helps A LOT. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with something like this as I felt the double `$` was messy.

```
define TEST_MACRO
   $(info B $(test_var))
endef

# Note test_var was defined after TEST_MACRO
test_var := test

$(eval $(value TEST_MACRO))
```

This has the disadvantage that you can't set the `$1..$n` variables but it's easier to read.

---

**Edit** - A better example of defining a variable inside of the macro. The above example was demonstrating how you would pass values into the macro, like you would with `call`

```
define TEST_MACRO
    test_var := test

    $(info B $(test_var))
endef
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Your original request was to define a variable inside a macro: this doesn't even come close to doing that?!  I assume you left out the `$` before `(value ...`, but even so this is just a confusing way to write `$(info B $(test_var))`... why bother with `eval` and `value`?

Comment: I wanted too be able to define variables inside of a macro, the above does allow me to do so without having to double `$` as that gets really confusing especially with bigger macros which is where I was heading with this. I'll add a better example.