# Defining variables inside macro initialized to shell output

Tags: gnu-make

This question is similar to [Defining Variables inside macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607558).

I've tried this with both GNU Make v3.82 and v4.3.  In the snippet below, I'm getting an error when I have a variable initialized with output from a shell statement from within a macro.  On my system, __LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION should be initialized with 11, which I then expect to be used in the initialization of __LINUX_GCC_V7_OR_LATER.  This does not appear to be happening, resulting in the syntax error from expr.

I've added $(info) statements to help with debugging.

```
LINUX_CC = gcc -m32

define __DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC
$(info [1])
__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION = $(shell $($(2)_CC) -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\..*//')
__$(2)_GCC_V7_OR_LATER  = $(shell expr $(__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION) \>= 7)
$(info [5])
endef

$(info [6])
$(eval $(call __DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC,linux,LINUX))

$(info [7])
# This outputs '11' as expected
$(info $(__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION))

$(info [8])
# This should be the result of "expr 11 >= 7", but the result is "FALSE"
ifeq ($(__LINUX_GCC_V7_OR_LATER),1)
V7 = "TRUE"
else
V7 = "FALSE"
endif
$(info $(V7))

$(info [9])

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo Done
```

```
~/temp/tmp$ make -f Makefile3
[6]
[1]
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘7’
[5]
[7]
11
[8]
"FALSE"
[9]
Done
```

What I expect to see is this:

```
~/temp/tmp$ make -f Makefile3
[6]
[1]
[5]
[7]
11
[8]
"TRUE"
[9]
Done
```

Why is this not working as desired, and what do I need to do to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to debug `eval` issues is with `info`.  Repeat the same line as the `eval` but replace the `eval` with `info`, and make will print out the section of makefile that `eval` will parse.

The problem, as with basically every `eval` issue that ever existed, is not fully understanding how expansion works.  Consider this line:

```
$(eval $(call __DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC,linux,LINUX))
```

How does make handle it?  As with ALL expansion, it works from the "inside out".  So first the innermost variables are expanded, moving from left to right (but here we don't have any values at the same level so that doesn't matter).  This means that the first thing make does is expand this:

```
$(call __DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC,linux,LINUX)
```

This is very simple string replacement here: `call` has no concept of makefile syntax.  It's just expanding the value of the first argument interpreted as a variable name `__DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC` with `$1` set to `linux` and `$2` set to `LINUX`.  How does this work?  The variable value is:

```
$(info [1])
__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION = $(shell $($(2)_CC) -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\..*//')
__$(2)_GCC_V7_OR_LATER  = $(shell expr $(__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION) \>= 7)
$(info [5])
```

so we start expanding.  Remember, for `call` this is *just a string*.  It has no concept of make syntax.  So first it expands the `$(info [1])` and prints out `[1]`.  Then it expands `__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION =`  and the result is `__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION =` .  Then it expands the shell command, which first expands the arguments to the shell, which will expand `$($(2)_CC)` to `gcc -m32`, so it will run the shell command:

```
gcc -m32 -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\..*//'
```

which will print `11`, so so far we've expanded the `call` function to:

```
__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION = 11
```

But crucially, and I repeat, this is *just a string*.  We have not actually set the make variable `__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION` to `11`.  As far as make is concerned this could be `zippity doo dah 11`.

Then we go to the next line:

```
__$(2)_GCC_V7_OR_LATER  = $(shell expr $(__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION) \>= 7)
$(info [5])
```

Now we expand this the same way, and here when we get to `$(__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION)` this variable **is not set**, because we're still in the `call`.  And so it expands to empty, and the shell runs `expr  \>= 7` which is invalid syntax and you get the error you see.

Here's the trick when working with `eval` and `call` together:

As a general rule the content of the variable should *escape* all `$` except for the `call` arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc.)

This way, all those `$` are passed through the `call` and not expanded, and then the `eval` will expand them.  So rewrite your define like this:

```
define __DECLARE_VERSION_FLAGS_GCC
$(info [1])
__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION = $$(shell $$($(2)_CC) -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\..*//')
__$(2)_GCC_V7_OR_LATER  = $$(shell expr $$(__$(2)_GCC_MAIN_VERSION) \>= 7)
$(info [5])
endef
```

(whether you escape the `$(info ...)` is up to you since it has no impact on the result of the expansion).

Now after the call, the shell etc. will not have run yet and you'll pass this string to the `eval`:

```
__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION = $(shell $(LINUX)_CC) -dumpversion | sed -e 's/\..*//')
__LINUX_GCC_V7_OR_LATER  = $(shell expr $(__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION) \>= 7)
```

and then it will work: eval will first set the `__LINUX_GCC_MAIN_VERSION` variable, then when it gets to the second line it will be set.